# Displaying images through Item.objects.all in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

In my index.html, I am trying to grab the 10 latest (comic book) issues by sorting through date added and then having the cover image of those issues on display through a table like this: http://www.comicbookresources.com/previews

Models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Cover', 'Cover'),    
    ('Scan', 'Scan'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    contributor = models.ManyToManyField(Contributor, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']        

class Issue(models.Model):

    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)
    number = models.IntegerField(help_text="Do not include the '#'.")

    ....

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="images_inc", blank=True, null=True)

    ....


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s #%s' % (self.title, self.number)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/issues/%s" % self.slug     
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    ....

    all_characters = Character.objects.all().filter(is_featured=True).order_by('name')
    latest_issues = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added')[:10]

    ....

    t = loader.get_template('comics/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'all_characters': all_characters,
        'latest_issues': latest_issues,
       })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Now, here is how my index.html file is setup:

```
{% for issue in latest_issues %} 
<li class="gallery">
<a href="{{ issue.get_absolute_url }}">
<img alt="{{ issue.title }} #{{ issue.number }}" title="{{ issue.title }} #{{ issue.number }}" src="{{ issue.images }}"></a>
<em>{{ issue.title }} #{{ issue.number }}</em>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ issue.images }}` displays one of those ManyToManyDBManagex34982423 things and `{{ issue.images.all }}` displays something like "Image: Astonishing X-Men 1 Cover A" while `{{ issue.images.url }`} displays nothing.

**I need it to display the cover image and more, specifically, I need it display ONE image that is categorized as 'Cover,'** because sometimes there are variant covers, and I wouldn't want it to display two covers of one issue. I'm sure I'd have to fix my views.py, but how would I go about doing this and then how would I display it in my template?

Baby talk. I am new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not slicing, you are getting index 10:

views.py:

```
latest_issues = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added')[10]
```

you would want:

```
latest_issues = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added')[:10]
```

To display all the cover images for an issue:

```
{% for image in issue.images.all %}
    {% if image.category == 'Cover' %}
    <img src='{{ image.image.url }}' />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a property on the Issue class to hold the Image specified as a "cover". This keeps your template as simple as possible. If you're only wanting to display one cover, it might also make sense to add a clean method to your model admin (or wherever you're doing editing on the Issue model) to only allow one image to be specified as a "cover".

```
#NOT TESTED
#models.py
from django.utils.functional import memoize

class Issue(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True, null=True)

    @memoize
    @property # @property means this is read-only
    def cover(self):
        return self.images.filter(category__exact='Cover')[:1]

#views.py
def index(request):
    latest_issues = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added').select_related(depth=1)[:10]
    return render(request, 'comics/index.html',
        {'latest_issues' : latest_issues})

#latest_issues.html
{% for issue in latest_issues %} 
<li class="gallery">
    <a href="{{ issue.get_absolute_url }}">
        <img alt="{{ issue.title }} #{{ issue.number }}" title="{{ issue.title }}
            #{{ issue.number }}" src="{{ issue.cover.url }}">
    </a>
    <em>{{ issue.title }} #{{ issue.number }}</em>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You might consider using integers to hold the values for the categories instead of strings, and also putting the choices and choices tuple into a separate file so you can access them in more than one place a little easier. I tend to put these into a "constants.py" file, even though Python doesn't have constants.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Good answer - one refinement would be to memoize the `cover` property so that multiple calls don't hit the database multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I completely forgot about the built-in memoize: django.core.utils.functional.memoize - obviously I need more coffee before posting answers.

Comment: Grr. memoize is at: django.utils.functional in 1.3